# SQlite multiple table references

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I'm not 100% sure I picked the correct title to this questions.. I've not done much work with SQlite or databases in general.

I'd have tried to google a solution if I knew what I needed to search!

So here's an example of what I want to achieve.

I have a Cars Table and a Workers Table,
Cars Table is made up of `carID`, `carName` and I want to add a Workers field.. in this field I want to be able to list a number of workers that worked on the certain car.

The Workers table will be as follows - `workerID`, `workerName`, `dateStarted`, `salary`.

The idea is to list a certain car I.E `carID: 1, carName: Ford Ka, workers[joe, bob, jim]` and be able to access their individual properties?

Thanks, I'm not sure if this has been answered anywhere.

Comment: Add a third `[WorkedOn]` table with `carID` and `workerID` columns and put the data in there - You should never store multiple values in a single field, that way lies madness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Best / nicest way to solve this (and not have redundant data) is to make a third table with the id's of the car and worker table eg NormalizationTable(carID, workerID, dateStarted, Salary) so when a worker has worked on a car you add a record. The key for that table would be the carID, workerID.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Why would `dateStarted` and `Salary` be in the junction table?

Comment: Asuming the dateStarted and the Salary are specific to when a worker worked on a car (you could call the table Project).... the junction table is the place to put those.

Of course if the salary of the worker stays the same no matter what car he works on then the place to put it is the worker table. Same goes for the dateStarted (I thought you ment the date he started working on a car not when he started his job)